# How can i style data gotten from mysql in php in my flutter app?

Tags: php, flutter, dart

Basically, all i see around is the ListTile and i can't style it,

```
ListTile(
    title: Text(document['title']),
    subtitle: Text(document['type']),
 ),
```

Is there another way whereby i can style my output?

Answer (score 1):

I tried Container widget when i deleted the ListTile and it works